# Select on which page a view has to be display

Tags: views

I am new to the Views module in Drupal 7. I enable the Taxonomy Term view and customize it a bit. For now the view is displayed in the default page of my theme in the main content region. But I would like this view to be displayed in a custom page defined by my theme on a particular region.
It seems to be an easy task but I can't figure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy, Edit your View and Click on Add (A popup near upper left) and choose `Block`

This newly created block will inherit all the settings from your existing view display.

You can Override any setting for your block display.

Choose appropriate template relevant to block following Theme: Information

Save your view and head on to block listing page to adjust your newly created block.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I test your solution but nothing appear in the region within I put the new created block.

Comment: Make sure if you are not using any argument and there is not any contextual condition.

Comment: Deleting contextual filter do nothing. The problem is not that the view has nothing to display, because if I set a header or a footer for the block it don't appear

Comment: Ok finally I succeed in displaying the block by disabling/enabling the view !